# Empty Pivot Cache when creating a pivot table in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, pivot-table

I'm using code from https://excelchamps.com/blog/vba-to-create-pivot-table/ to create a pivot table in a long macro I'm writing. The pivot table recently stopped working; this sub runs with no errors but there is no sign of the pivot table. Was fully functional until recently. On trying to troubleshoot I've found the PCache variable is empty, I'm assuming this is where everything is breaking down. The only thing changed since this was working is I changed the cell formats of two columns in the data range for the pivot table, however they seem irrelevant and are not being used for the pivot table.

I have also recorded my own macro to try and fix this. Manually creating the pivot table works fine but this is not a solution to my problem. The recorded macro from this does not work however. I have tried code from multiple different sites as well and have used non-variable ranges but nothing has worked.

```
Sub bpPivotTBL()
'https://excelchamps.com/blog/vba-to-create-pivot-table/
Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long


'??Declare Variables
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("PIPE PIVOT").Delete
Sheets.Add Before:=Worksheets("INCOMING")
ActiveSheet.Name = "PIPE PIVOT"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set PSheet = Worksheets("PIPE PIVOT")
Set DSheet = Worksheets("INCOMING")


LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

'=================================================================
'Define Pivot Cache
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), _
TableName:="PipePivot")
'==================================================================

'?Insert Blank Pivot Table
Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="PipePivot")


'Insert Row Fields
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PipePivot").PivotFields("CNCT")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 1
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're not getting an error is that you've included an On Error statement, which masks any errors.  If you comment out or delete that line, you'll get an error here...

```
'Define Pivot Cache
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
    (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
    CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), _
    TableName:="PipePivot")
```

That instruction first creates a pivot cache, then it creates a pivot table, and then it tries to assign the pivot table to PCache, which has been declared as a PivotCache.  As a result, you'll get an error.  So create only the pivot cache, and then assign it to PCache...

```
'Define Pivot Cache
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
    (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)
```

Comment: So I'm still getting an error (Run-time 440) from the shortened line you suggested: Method 'Create' of object 'PivotCaches' failed. Nothing before you line has been changed. Got any ideas? Thanks

Comment: When I tested it, it created the pivot table without any errors.  Does it help if an R1C1 reference style string is used to specify the source data  ---> `SourceData:=PRange.Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True)` ?

Comment: So yesterday I got it working just by not using variables when creating the table. (Not sure why this worked but it did). Today my new code started giving me the same problems my old code gave me. Tried the R1C1 thing to no avail. Shai Rado's solution is giving me the same problem. P.S. Thanks for the help!

Comment: With the R1C1 reference string, did you get an error?  If so, which one?  Also, do you have any invalid column headers, such as blank headers?  Also, try converting your data into a table (Ribbon >> Insert >> Tables >> Table) and using the table as the source data.  For example, let's say that your table is named "Table1", use  `SourceData:="Table1"`.

Comment: Found the culprit - One of my column headers is a reference that is sometimes made null by the VBA right before the pivot table runs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, explanations inside the code's comments:

```
' =================================================================
' Set the Pivot Cache Range
Dim SrcData As String
SrcData = PRange.Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal)

' Define and Set the Pivot Cache
Set PCache = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=SrcData)
'==================================================================

' create a new Pivot Table in "PIPE PIVOT" sheet
Set PTable = PSheet.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PCache, TableDestination:=PSheet.Range("A1"), TableName:="PipePivot")

'Insert Row Fields
With PTable.PivotFields("CNCT") ' <<-- Once you set the Pivot-Table, you can use this object in your With Statements
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
```

Comment: I just thought I would point out that the keyword `Set` isn't needed when assigning the reference string to `SrcData`, as Shai Rado very well knows.  No doubt, a minor oversight.

Comment: Still getting  a blank table - my error may be somewhere else.